yt_dlp about downloading video from youtube
How can I download video bytes only without downloading it in a file because I need to deploy it on a host and the host doesn't support file writing and reading.
from io import BytesIO
import yt_dlp

# Specify the URL of the YouTube video you want to download
video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID_HERE'

# Set options for the downloader
options = {
    'format': 'best',  # Choose the best quality format available
}

# Create a downloader object
ydl = yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(options)

# Download the video and store it directly in a variable
video_data = BytesIO()

with ydl:
    ydl.download([video_url], out=video_data)

# Now video_data contains the downloaded video 


Are you sure? This can eat all your RAM in a moment or two...
